# Error converting value "09:00" to type xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, xamarin.forms, json.net

i try hard but i dont find the issue i try to show json hours in my app but i have this error "Error converting value "09:00" to type...."
My json GET:

```
[
"09:00",
"10:00",
"11:30",
"12:30",
"13:30",
"15:00",
"16:00",
"17:00"]
```

My code ApiService:

```
      public static async Task<List<Availabilities>> GetAvailabilities()
    {

        var userName = "marcelo";
        var passwd = "PWD.";
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var authToken = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{userName}:{passwd}");
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", Convert.ToBase64String(authToken));     
        
        var response = await httpClient.GetStringAsync(AppSettings.ApiUrl + "index.php/api/v1/availabilities?providerId=4&serviceId=12&date=2020-07-26");

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Availabilities>>(response);
       


    }
```

My Availabilities.cs:

```
   public class Availabilities
{

  public string Hours {get; set;}
}
```

My Availabilities.xaml.cs

```
        public ObservableCollection<Availabilities> AvailabilitiesCollection;
    public PageAvailabilities()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        AvailabilitiesCollection = new ObservableCollection<Availabilities>();
        GetAvailabilities();

    }


    private async void GetAvailabilities()
    {

        var hours = await ApiService.GetAvailabilities();
        foreach (var hour in hours)
        {

           AvailabilitiesCollection.Add(hour.ToString());
        }
        CvAvailabilities.ItemsSource = AvailabilitiesCollection;
    }
```

Please can someone explain me how to do this request:) ?
Best regard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont have a list of objects that have strings. You only have a list of strings

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(response)
```

Answer (score 1):

your json is just a `string[]`.  You will need to deserialize it first, then convert it to your type

```
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(response);

// using LINQ
var hours = from x in data select 
  new Availabilities { Hours = x }).ToList<Availabilities>(); 

return hours;
```

Comment: Hello thank you a lot for your answers but it to complicate for me sorry :/ i use the other reponse but thanks for your time Jason :)